# ElasticSearch query to populate or append a value to a field

Tags: elasticsearch

Our ElasticSearch index has documents with a field called `SourceId`(never blank), and a field called `CustomCategories`.  The `CustomCategories` field can be blank, or can contain anywhere from 1 to 10 comma-separated 5-character codes.

I need to add the custom category code `ABCDE` to all documents that contain SourceIds 1,2,3,4,10,15,20,22.

What is an ElasticSearch query that I can run for this, keeping in mind that if the `CustomCategories` field is blank, I just need it to be populated with `ABCDE`, whereas if that field is NOT blank, I need to append `,ABCDE` to the end of whatever value is there?

**EDIT 1**: per request from @jaspreet_chahal here is an example document, as well as the mapping for the `customCategories` field:

**Document**

```
 {
                "_index": "index123",
                "_type": "wls_doc",
                "_id": "JqkGxmYBwD-D6of2dr43",
                "_score": 1.0,
                "_source": {
                    "address": null,
                    "age": null,
                    "aliasList": null,
                    "caution": null,
                    "dateOfBirth": null,
                    "eyeColor": null,
                    "gender": null,
                    "hairColor": null,
                    "height": null,
                    "identifier": null,
                    "nationality": null,
                    "placeOfBirth": null,
                    "program": null,
                    "race": null,
                    "remarks": null,
                    "text": null,
                    "weight": null,
                    "entities": null,
                    "individualName": "John Doe",
                    "capturedDateTime": "2018-04-17T01:19:52.0131214",
                    "sourceId": 1,
                    "captureId": 194857,
                    "sourceAgencyAcronym": "ABC",
                    "sourceAgencyName": "Another Bad Creation",
                    "sourceCountry": "USA",
                    "sourceParentAgency": "Contoso",
                    "sourceRegion": "United States",
                    "url": "http://www.contoso.org",
                    "categories": [
                        "ABCDE",
                        "FGHIJ",
                        "KLMNO"
                    ],
                    "customCategories": [
                        "XA001",
                        "XB001"
                    ]
                }
            }
```

**Mapping for customCategories field:**

```
                  "customCategories": {
                        "type": "text",
                        "fields": {
                            "keyword": {
                                "type": "keyword",
                                "ignore_above": 256
                            }
                        }
                    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [update by query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-update-by-query.html) and a Painless script.

Data:

```
[
      {
        "_index" : "index42",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "YqgIAW4BgXknAapksgky",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "SourceId" : 1,
          "CustomCategories" : "abc"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "index42",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "Y6gIAW4BgXknAapkxQl0",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "SourceId" : 2,
          "CustomCategories" : ""
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "index42",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "ZKgIAW4BgXknAapk1wlV",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "SourceId" : 3,
          "CustomCategories" : "abc"
        }
      }
    ]
```

Query:

```
POST index24/_update_by_query
{
  "script": {
    "source": "def categories=ctx._source.customCategories;if(categories ==null){ctx._source.customCategories= new ArrayList()}else ctx._source.customCategories.add(params.catg)",
    "lang": "painless",
    "params":{"catg":"xyz"}
  }
}
```

Response:

```
 [
      {
        "_index" : "index42",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "ZKgIAW4BgXknAapk1wlV",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "SourceId" : 3,
          "CustomCategories" : ["abc"]
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "index42",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "YqgIAW4BgXknAapksgky",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "SourceId" : 1,
          "CustomCategories" : ["abc","xyz"] --> new value appened
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "index42",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "Y6gIAW4BgXknAapkxQl0",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "SourceId" : 2,
          "CustomCategories" : ["xyz"] --> new value added
        }
      }
    ]
```

Comment: Checking this now.  Thanks!

Comment: Hi, it partially worked.  2 strange things after I ran the query: 1) before the query was run, a given `customCategories` field looked like this: `"customCategories": "XA001, XB001"`  After running the query (using new code XC001), the field now looks like this: `"customCategories": "[XA001, XB001], XC001, "`  Any ideas what's going on there, and also what would be the query to fix these to put them back how they were? I'll put the second odd thing I'm seeing in the next comment.

Comment: What is type of custom categories is it text or object/nested

Comment: It's type `text`.

Comment: 2) before running the query, our documents would display with the fields in the order in which we designed the schema - after running the query, our documents are displaying with the fields in alphabetical order?? This is only happening for the source that I've tested your query on.

Comment: Can a add a sample document in code, will help me replicate it-before version

Comment: You bet - I'll add it as an edit to my post - give me about 5 minutes.

Comment: Ok, see Edit 1 in the main post.

Comment: I was considering categories to be like “a,b”  .script converted array of string to string value(on appending) I have added edit to append to array of string , test it out before  working on actual data. To correct existing data probably a ingest preprocessor or script needs to be written to split and replace text and add to a aray or if you can reindex it will be easier.

Comment: Thanks! This one looks good - it is working correctly on the documents where it appends to an existing array.  Just trying to find an example now where the field is blank to make sure that works correctly as well.  As soon as I confirm that, I will mark this as the answer.