# Elasticsearch query to remove an delete value from inconsistent array of comma-separated values

Tags: elasticsearch

Recently, I posted the following about adding a string to existing (inconsistent) arrays in documents:  [ElasticSearch query to populate or append a value to a field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58548799/elasticsearch-query-to-populate-or-append-a-value-to-a-field)

The marked solution is working perfectly.

But now I need to understand how to *delete* one of the 5-character codes from the arrays.  Assuming I now need to delete the code 'ABCDE' from the documents, while leaving the other codes in the array untouched, what would that query look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In below script I am looping through array and creating a list by removing the given value.

Please test before running on actual data.

```
{
  "script": {
    "source": "ctx._source.customCategories.removeAll(Collections.singleton(params.catg))",
    "lang": "painless",
    "params": {
      "catg": "c"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi Jaspreet. Good to see you again. I will try this after my morning meeting. In the meantime, can you suggest some online documentation or video tutorial for me to learn the painless language and syntax for ES?

Comment: This is official documentation https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/index.html

Comment: Hi Jaspreet.  I've run your query on some test sources.  The query does remove the custom category value as intended, but, it's doing that thing again where the fields are displayed out of order for any documents which I've run the query against.  You were able to somehow address this in the other post.  Can you please advise?

Comment: Just FYI, sample document and mapping are identical to the other thread.  Thanks.

Comment: I have updated the answer. I think this should work fine

Comment: HI Jaspreet.  The out-of-order results is still happening.  I don't know if this is happening as a result of running your query, or not.  All I can say is I view sourceId 1 documents before running the query and the fields are in the correct order, then I run your query, then look at sourceId 1 documents again, and the fields are out of order.  The fields are only out of order on the documents related to sourceId's against which I've run this query.  It's very odd.

Comment: Can you give sample data to replicate this

Comment: Document before running update query: https://api.myjson.com/bins/11o4rw
Run query: https://api.myjson.com/bins/gtylo
Document after running query: https://api.myjson.com/bins/dz2wc

Comment: Initially you have two values in customcategory . On deleting one value is left. Do you intend to replace first value or keep it empty?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question.  The customcategory field can have anywhere from zero to 10 values in it.  The query that we are working on is intended to delete one of those values, and the array then have the remaining values left in it.  There is no intent to replace the value which gets deleted.

Comment: I was looking into the links you added. In first link there are only 2 values and in 3 rd link one is left. So not able to see the values in disorder. Can you add or update link with multiple custom categories where you are able to see the issue

Comment: No that's not the issue - the issue is that the fields of the DOCUMENT are displayed out-of-order after the query is run.  Note the order of the document fields before and after the query.

Comment: Document is a json file where order is not guaranteed and should not matter too as  values are always read using field name.

Comment: Yes I must agree with you there.  Ok, I'll mark your answer and discuss this internally with my developers.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: Glad could be of help